# Jagged Array ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, arrays, jagged-arrays

I have the following code to produce a jagged array as vertical columns, however, when it gets to the second set of numbers, it says it is out of bounds. Why is this?

this is the code in question. nums1 each has a length of 3, however,  with nums2, it seem to be getting the longest length of the array

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double nums1[][] =
    {
        {
            1, 2, 3
        }, 
        {
            4, 5, 6
        }, 
        {
            7, 8, 9
        }
    };
    double nums2[][] ={ {3.23, 4.28, 2.63, 2.89},{1.63, 8.46, 4.11},{0.23, 7.14, 1.26, 9.16, 8.01},{4.20}
    };

    System.out.println("\n\nPrint nums1 vertically");
    printVertical(nums1);

    System.out.println("\n\nPrint nums2 vertically");
   printVertical(nums2);
}

public static void printVertical(double[][] nums)
{
    for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(nums[j][i] + "      ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Col " + (i + 1) + "    ");
    }
}
```

}

the error message:

```
3.0      6.0      9.0
2.0      5.0      8.0
1.0      4.0      7.0 Col 1    Col 2    Col 3

Print nums2 vertically
2.89
2.63      4.11      1.26      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 1
        at test.printVertical(test.java:29)
        at test.main(test.java:22)
```

Comment: if you check for `nums[i].length` in `j` and then do `nums[j][i]`, you might get into trouble :)

Comment: @zapl i need `nums[j][i]` to be able to have the columns print in the correct order. Is there `nums[i].length` so the formatting is still correct?

Comment: I think by swapping your i and j loops, you have to use the correct limits, if `nums[5].length` is 3, then `nums[5][0]` to `num[5][2]` is all that is possible

Comment: @zapl unfortunately, swapping i and j loops causes columns to be printed horizontally, and not vertically like a need

Comment: like this maybe? https://jdoodle.com/ia/wgF